# Icinga IDO schema error

Tags: icinga

I was going through the steps to setup icinga on a server with the icingaweb UI v 2.0 layout as given in their [documentation](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc). I was successful in getting to the setup page, which requires you to put in a token and then follow the steps. Im stuck at this spot

[image: screen cap]

(see screenshot) right now which requires you to setup an IDO database which I already did as shown:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| icinga             |
| icinga2idomysql    |
| icinga_ido         |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

However I keep getting the error message `Cannot find the IDO schema. Please verify that the given database contains the schema and that the configured user has access to it.`. Can anyone help me or point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How did you setup icinga2, especially the name of the IDO database? I'd blindly guess it is 'icinga' and not 'icinga_ido'.

Comment: Have a look at the discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162838/icinga2-ido-schema/38628013#38628013

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but, before a few hours looking for the solution, i found the answer in the following url:

https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/how-to-install-and-configure-icinga2-monitoring-tool-on-ubuntu-16-04-a582e949dd40

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's better to include at least a summary of the solution, so your answer will still be useful when the linked content goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This was done a few steps before this step. Maybe the install took you days
and you didn´t recognize it anymore, like I me ;)

```
sudo egrep "(^dbc_dbuser|^dbc_dbname|^dbc_dbpass)" /etc/dbconfig-common/icinga2-ido-mysql.conf
```

> dbc_dbuser='icinga2' dbc_dbpass='password' dbc_dbname='icinga2'